# Memory leak while freeing a hash table C

Tags: c

I am working on a pset and I am having an error message: Looks like you're trying to use a variable that might not have a value? It says that cursor has not been initialised.I bolded the row where the error comes from.

I heed some help how to fix it, please.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *cursor = table[i]; // place cursor to each bucket
        node *tmp = cursor; // create a tmp equal to cursor
        **while(cursor!= NULL)**
        {
            cursor = cursor->next; // move cursor to the next node
            free (tmp);
            tmp = cursor;
        }
        if (i == N-1)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and give the **exact** error message.

Comment: What is `table`?

Comment: It sounds like you forgot to initialize the member `next` when creating new node. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What's the point of the `if` statement? Why not just return true after the loop is done?

Comment: @Kaylum, that is the message: Program is not free from memory leaks, when as run valgrind for clarification, it says: Looks like you're trying to use a variable that might not have a value and highlights cursor in the while loop.

Comment: @Barmar, the requirement of the pset is to return both true and false. I tried it without as you suggested but I am still having the same error message.

Comment: @MikeCAT, thanks I will check now.

Comment: @Loading My comment has nothing to do with the error message. Under what circumstances is it supposed to return `false`? It looks like it will always return `true`, because the `if` condition will always be true on the last iteration.

Comment: FYI, this is not a memory leak, it's an uninitialized variable.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you. You are correct, it did not make sense to me either , I was just trying to somehow add return false. I removed it now and left just return true. I initialised new_node->next, as MikeCAT suggested and all works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is a bit awkward, and the function always returns `true` if `N > 0`. Yet your code seems fine and frees all the nodes. The memory leak is elsewhere: do the nodes have pointers to allocated memory (besides `next`)?

Here is a simpler version:

```
int free_table(node *table, int N) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        node *cursor = table[i];       // use cursor to enumerate the bucket list
        table[i] = NULL;               // optional
        while (cursor != NULL) {
            node *next = cursor->next; // save the next pointer
            free(cursor);
            cursor = next;
        }
    }
    return N > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @chqrlie . This make more sense to me as well, but the condition is the function to return bool. I found now my mistake, new_node->next was not initialized.